# How to write sql query for following scenario?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table Employee with column Firstname and Lastname?

how to write query for creating new column fullname and put concatenate value of firstname and lastname in that column for all the corresponding columns values simultaneously.

Comment: Looks like a question which you can answer ten minutes after to have START to learn SQL. So what you did so far ? Clue : SELECT Firstname + ' ' + Lastname as Fullname

Comment: i do not want to write two different queries.i want to do all the things in single query(By using Procedure or whatevere).

Comment: I have almost gave you the answer ! If you prefer : "SELECT Firstname, Lastname, Firstname + ' ' + Lastname as Fullname from YourTable" for a SELECT. And use the  Kartik73 if you want to really create the new column. And PLEASE search by yourself !

Comment: This is SQL 101 stuff and has no relation to PL/SQL. Flagging for poor quality post.

Answer (score 3):

First add a column `fullname`.

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD fullname VARCHAR(60);
```

Then you can add data by adding the other 2 columns.

```
UPDATE Table table_name 
SET fullname = concat(firstname, ' ', lastname);
```

Comment: i do not want to write two different queries.i want to do all the things in single query(By using Procedure or whatevere).

Answer (score 1):

First of all alter your table to add extra column:

Ex for mysql.

```
ALTER TABLE contacts ADD fullname VARCHAR(60);
```

than fire query(Mysql):

```
UPDATE Table table_name SET fullname= concat( firstname, ' ', lastname)
```

Find similar for database you use.

Comment: i do not want to write two different queries.i want to do all the things in single query(By using Procedure or whatevere).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if any other way exists. See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185458/quickly-add-a-copy-of-a-column-to-a-mysql-table) helps